# Get Public Profile Url by Search LinkedIn

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, linkedin-api

I want to search other users by giving firstname, lastname, email, or phone number and get other user public profile url

I am currently doing this by using Api Request

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:first-name=bill&last-name=gates

But getting error 
"Access to people search denied."

So how do i achieve my desired result to get public profile url which other user set

Comment: Are you a linkedin parter? https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

Comment: @luk2302 no i am not , is it mandatory to become linkedin partner ?

Answer (score 0):

There API has changed to version 2 so the usage for the Profile API would now be.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people-search:first-name=bill&last-name=gates
```

you can find more information about their Profile API v2 [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/profile-api)

You will be needing an access token to access there profile api, without the auth key you will get

```
{"serviceErrorCode":401,"message":"Empty oauth2 access token","status":401}
```

Comment: Can i use this using Mobile SDK provided by Linkedin ?

Comment: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?oauth2_access_token=YOUR_ACCESS
_TOKEN_HERE